# Ushare rescan filesystem without restarting

Tags: linux, upnp, dlna

I'm using Ushare as an UPnP / DLNA media server. It works nice, however it has an annoying drawback. I need to manually restart it to rescan the filesystem.

Is there any way/method to

- rescan the filesystem without restart (not-so-good solution)
- dynamically push new files to the library (perfect solution)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.  Would it be more appropriate for [super user](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: I think it's a programming issue, since basicly it hasn't got any option to do this. But it's opensource, my question would be more precisely: which part of Ushare source should I modify to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no auto-rescan feature in uShare and I don't think it's being developed any more, but you can make it periodically rescan if you use a cron job. There's a blog post about how to do it here: http://ramonecung.com/blog/2009/05/ushare-linuxu-buntu-based-media-server-auto-refresh/

An alternative is to use MiniDLNA which does a similar thing and does allow rescanning without restarting the server (although there's no browser-based UI): https://github.com/azatoth/minidlna